# CSS Image Hover Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a pseudo hover to a `<a>` tag, but no image is showing with either css class. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong as I am new to css.

```
#AIM a {
    left:420px;
    top:590px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim.png');
}
#AIM a:hover {
    left:420px;
    top:590px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim-hover.png');
}
```

`<a id="AIM" href="http://dribbble.com/_max" />`

Comment: Do you have a link to a work in progress or example? Right now, I'm guessing that your selector is slightly off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A tag has no idea how big your image is. A is also an inline element, so it stretches to the size of its content (usually the text inside).

You need to:

- Define width and height (I'm using 300px)
- Make it a block element

  {
          display: block;
          width:300px;
          height:300px;
          left:420px;
          top:590px;
          position: absolute;
          background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim.png');
      }

Answer (score 2):

You `<a>` has no width or height so there is nowhere for a background image to display.

`#AIM a` is  a selector for anchor tags inside an element with id `#AIM` like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/5yg7t/. You want to select an anchor tag with `id="AIM"` in which case you should just use an ID selector since ID's are unique. Use this:

```
#AIM {
    left:420px;
    top:590px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 54px;
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim.png');
}

#AIM:hover {
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim-hover.png');
}
```

[***JSFiddle Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/G2p2q/)

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, I didn't see that little bit of HTML at the bottom of his post, and assumed his `<a>` was in an element with id `AIM`. I fixed my post

Answer (score 0):

`#AIM a` matches `<a>` tags *inside of* `#AIM`.
You need to write `a#AIM` to match `<a>` tags *that are* `#AIM`.

You can also just write `#AIM`, since IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tags have no content, so they'll be effectively 0x0 invisible elements. Either add some text:

```
<a ...>&nbsp;</a>
```

or give them a size in the CSS:

```
a#AIM {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}
```

or better yet, both.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to the following

```
a#AIM {
    left:420px;
    top:590px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim.png');
}
a#AIM:hover {
    left:420px;
    top:590px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://maxk.me/img/aim-hover.png');
}
```

Change the HTML to the following

```
<a id="AIM" href="http://dribbble.com/_max" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to both classes; then try specifying a width and height...

```
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
```